# Changing product SKU - SEO impact

Tags: seo

I'm going to renew my e-commerce website. Since products' SKUs are very long I was thinking about changing them with something shorter.

Could product SKU changing have bad result on SEO side?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the following.

1. SKU's are not part of key elements like `H1` tags.
2. You are not going to change the URLs (happens if you have included SKUs as part of the URL).
3. SKU's are not part of users' **search queries**.

In the above-described scenario changing shouldn't have a noticeable impact. Experienced members can correct me if I am wrong.

If the site is too large and you are too much concerned about the SEO impacts, you could pilot a few "**less risky**" pages first (the products which rank reasonably well but don't bring in much ROI), observe the traffic for those pages for a few months, and decide for the whole site later.

P.S: There is another thread that raises a similar issue like yours :
[Does constantly doing small edits to a website affect its SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113058/does-constantly-doing-small-edits-to-a-website-affect-its-seo). The top rated answer is fairly explanatory. The explanation under the final paragraph below the title "So what does a few simple changes to content do?" should apply to your scenario as well.

Comment: It's something like this: `url: https://www.example.com/my-beautiful-product-2005-2010-en.html` while `sku: my-beautiful-product_2005-2010_en`. Url will not change and I think users don't search for SKU but SKU is similar to product name. I want change the SKU in something like `MPY001`. What do you think?

Comment: Are you saying you are going to retain the old SKU in URL but change the SKU internally? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm saying my URLs won't change as well as H1 tags (which looks like `My Beautiful Product (2005-2010) [EN]`) but I'd like to change the SKU which now is `my-beautiful-product_2005-2010_en` with something shorter like `MPY001`. Could this hurt SEO?

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't be worried. You can consider your edits as minor changes with least impact on SEO. If you are too concerned and want to be doubly sure, you can pilot a few pages as I have mentioned in my answer. Also, I would recommend you to read the thread https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113058/does-constantly-doing-small-edits-to-a-website-affect-its-seo which kind of fits your case.